# Clearing the buffer, output firstname,lastname

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I am having problems with my program. If I remove the `in.nextLine` the firstname and lastname println's will print one after another and if I have it in, it will not print the first name in my output as I think it is removing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Utilities
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Variables
    int studentId = 0;
    String lastName = "";
    String firstName = "";
    String gradeLetter = "";
    String quit = "";
    double userHomeworkScore = 0.0;
    double userQuizzesScore = 0.0;
    double userMidTermScore = 0.0;
    double userFinalScore = 0.0;
    double homeworkScore = 0.0;
    double quizzesScore = 0.0;
    double midTermScore = 0.0;
    double finalScore = 0.0;
    double totalScore = 0.0;

    do {


        System.out.println("Please enter Student ID");
        studentId = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter first name");
        firstName = in.nextLine();

        in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter last name");
        lastName = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter score for the assignments");
        userHomeworkScore = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter score for the quizzes");
        userQuizzesScore = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter score for the midterm");
        userMidTermScore = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter score for the final");
        userFinalScore = in.nextDouble();

        String fullName = (firstName + "," + lastName);

        homeworkScore = (userHomeworkScore * 0.50);
        quizzesScore = (userQuizzesScore * 0.20);
        midTermScore = (userMidTermScore * 0.10);
        finalScore = (userFinalScore * 0.20);

        totalScore = (homeworkScore+quizzesScore+midTermScore+finalScore);

        if (totalScore >= 90)
        {
            gradeLetter = "A";
        }
        else if (totalScore >= 80)
        {
            gradeLetter = "B";
        }
        else if (totalScore >= 70)
        {
            gradeLetter = "C";
        }
        else if (totalScore >= 60)
        {
            gradeLetter = "D";
        }
        else
        {
            gradeLetter = "E";
        }


        //Output
        System.out.println(""+fullName+"");
        System.out.println("Student ID:" + studentId + "");
        System.out.println("Homework:" + homeworkScore + "");
        System.out.println("Quizzes:" + quizzesScore + "");
        System.out.println("Midterm:" + midTermScore + "");
        System.out.println("Final:" + finalScore + "");
        System.out.println("Total Score: " + totalScore + " Grade: " + gradeLetter + "");

        System.out.println("Press any key to enter another student or enter q to quit.");
        quit = in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();

    }while(!quit.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));


}
```

}

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you are setting `String fullName = (firstName + "," + lastName);` before you read in `firstName` and `lastName`.

Comment: I tried moving it right above my output but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I was wrong it looks like it does so I moved the line down but how do I get it to scan in the first name and last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "Flush" the buffer after reading the integer.
The reason is that when you use `in.nextInt()` it only reads the int value and skips the "\n" (end of the line), using the `in.nextLine()`
will consume the "\n".

Use this

```
 System.out.println("Please enter Student ID");
        studentId = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
```

and of course after reading the last double

```
System.out.println("Please enter score for the final");
        userFinalScore = in.nextDouble();
        in.nextLine();
```

You don't need to "flush" between the two line readings.
This is wrong:

```
System.out.println("Please enter first name");
    firstName = in.nextLine();

    in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter last name");
    lastName = in.nextLine();
```

Another solution:
You can use `in.next()` to read the string.
`in.next()` Finds and returns the next complete token from the scanner.

while `in.nextLine()` since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Variables
    int studentId = 0;
    String lastName = "";
    String firstName = "";
    String gradeLetter = "";
    String quit = "";
    double userHomeworkScore = 0.0;
    double userQuizzesScore = 0.0;
    double userMidTermScore = 0.0;
    double userFinalScore = 0.0;
    double homeworkScore = 0.0;
    double quizzesScore = 0.0;
    double midTermScore = 0.0;
    double finalScore = 0.0;
    double totalScore = 0.0;

    do {


        System.out.println("Please enter Student ID");
        studentId = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter first name");
        firstName = in.next();



        System.out.println("Please enter last name");
        lastName = in.next();


        System.out.println("Please enter score for the assignments");
        userHomeworkScore = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter score for the quizzes");
        userQuizzesScore = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter score for the midterm");
        userMidTermScore = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter score for the final");
        userFinalScore = in.nextDouble();

        String fullName = (firstName + "," + lastName);

        homeworkScore = (userHomeworkScore * 0.50);
        quizzesScore = (userQuizzesScore * 0.20);
        midTermScore = (userMidTermScore * 0.10);
        finalScore = (userFinalScore * 0.20);

        totalScore = (homeworkScore+quizzesScore+midTermScore+finalScore);

        if (totalScore >= 90)
        {
            gradeLetter = "A";
        }
        else if (totalScore >= 80)
        {
            gradeLetter = "B";
        }
        else if (totalScore >= 70)
        {
            gradeLetter = "C";
        }
        else if (totalScore >= 60)
        {
            gradeLetter = "D";
        }
        else
        {
            gradeLetter = "E";
        }



        //Output
        System.out.println(""+fullName+"");
        System.out.println("Student ID:" + studentId + "");
        System.out.println("Homework:" + homeworkScore + "");
        System.out.println("Quizzes:" + quizzesScore + "");
        System.out.println("Midterm:" + midTermScore + "");
        System.out.println("Final:" + finalScore + "");
        System.out.println("Total Score: " + totalScore + " Grade: " + gradeLetter + "");

        System.out.println("Press any key to enter another student or enter q to quit.");
        quit = in.next();

    }while(!quit.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
```

The Output:

```
Please enter Student ID
1
Please enter first name
a
Please enter last name
b
Please enter score for the assignments
100
Please enter score for the quizzes
100
Please enter score for the midterm
100
Please enter score for the final
100
a,b
Student ID:1
Homework:50.0
Quizzes:20.0
Midterm:10.0
Final:20.0
Total Score: 100.0 Grade: A
Press any key to enter another student or enter q to quit.
q
```